# Excel IF(OR) formula determine investigate or not

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, range

I added a column to return weather the lost pounds is less than a specific percentage or more than to return “investigate” or “no”. Issue is each line has a specific range of percentages that I am unable to correlate in my formula. Photo is added for reference, how to add other lines in one formula as I am unable to split data for each line to different tabs, I would like them all in one spreadsheet. Check photo for reference.
[image]

Comment: May be this you need : `=IF((E2>=0.07)*(E2<=0.09),"Investigate","No")`

Comment: You haven’t correlated the line number as there are different percentages for each line and there are more than 1 line

Comment: Why do you want to correlate the whole range of percentages, shouldnt you correlate with the corresponding cells only here? If i may ask, please let me know so i can understand

Comment: Not the whole range of percentages but there are different lines 1 through 8 that have different range of percentages to determine if they need to be investigated based on orders. For example line08 I need to investigate lost pounds % that are less than 7% or more than or equal to 9%. Line07 I need to investigate lost pounds that are less than 20% or more than 22%. Line 06 I need only to investigate lost pounds that are less than 17% or more than 20%. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Yes clearly understood now, but how do you determine, that this line needs to compared with these two percentages or that lines to be compared with that, there should be some indicators.

Comment: Hey @trooper best to create a table of reference right. Low Range and high range, in the adjacent column right the lien 08 or 07 or 06. and next use a lookup function to match, by doing approximate match, that would work

Comment: are you able to understand ? please let me know?

Comment: Can you check this and confirm will it be somewhat like this ? **[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/bDmNxyP)**

Comment: Analysis Is done to determine each  line range lost pounds %. But I need my formula to include the line # so it can read if my data is the same in  column A  to return weather to investigate or not.

Comment: Please check the screenshot i have posted in my last comment.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I tried to use your formula but was faced with an error but yes this actually might be what I need. If you don’t mind can you copy and paste it just so I can make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: Yes may some tweaking needed, but this is the formula you need to place in cell `B2` and fill down note that you have to create the table of reference as well: `=IF(OR(E2>LOOKUP(--A2,$H$2:$H$9+0,$I$2:$I$9),E2<=LOOKUP(--A2,$H$2:$H$9+0,$J$2:$J$9)),"Investigate","No")`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you, you have indeed helped in solving this